# Syncing of memory and database objects upon changes in objects in memory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am currently implementing a web application in .net core(C#) using entity framework. While working on the project, I actually encountered quite a few challenges but I will start with the one which I think are most important. My questions are as follows:

1. Instead of frequent loading data from the database, I am having a set of static objects which is a mirror of the data in the database. However, it is tedious and error prone when I want to ensure any changes, i.e., adding/deleting/modifying of objects are being saved to the database at real time. Is there any good example or advice that I can refer to improve my approach to do this?
2. Another thing is that value of some objects' properties will be changed on the fly according to the value of some other objects' properties. Something like a spreadsheet where a cell's value will be changed automatically if the value in the cell that the formula is referring to changes. I do not have a solution to do this yet. Appreciate if anyone has any example that I can refer to. But this will add another layer of complexity to sync the changes of the objects in memory to database.

At the moment, I am unsure if there is any better approach. Appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks!

Comment: sounds to me like you've build yourself a datacontext that caches db objects around dbcontext, wich is in fact already a well functioning datacontext that caches db objects and implements tracking, maybe you should read about the basics of ef

Comment: I agree - it sounds like you are over engineering this. What is that actual issue with using the native built in capability of EF to read and write data?

Comment: @PatrickBeynio What I am trying to achieve to have the objects in memory is because of performance. A simple scenario that I will face is as follows:
I have 1 instance of object A, 100 instances of object B and 1000 instances of object C. In object A I have a property that will be recalculated automatically if a subset of object C's property value changes. I am foreseeing there will be a lot of heavy calculation thus I want to do it in memory. About saving to database, it is alright if it is not "real-time" but I need the data to be persistence in case of a server crash/error

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Hi Nick, please refers to my comment above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you're facing a problem that's called eventual consistency. Something changes and two or more systems need to be aware at the same time. The problem here is that both changes need to be applied in order to consider the operation successful. If either one fails, you need to know.

In your case, I would use the Azure Service Bus. You can create queues and put messages on a queue. An Azure Function would handle these queue messages. You would create two queues, one for database updates, and one for the in-memory update (I think changing this to a cache service may be something to think off). Now the advantage of these queues is that you can easily drop messages on these queues from anywhere. Because you mentioned the object is going to evolve, you may need to update these objects either in the database or in memory (cache).

Once you've done that, I'd create a topic, with two subscriptions. One forwarding messages to Queue 1, and the other to Queue 2. This will solve your primary problem. In case an object changes, just send it to the topic. Both changes (database and memory) will be executed automagically.

The only problem you have now, it that you mentioned you wanted to update the database in real-time. With this scenario, you're going to have to leave that.

Also, you need to make sure you have proper alerts in place for the queues so in case you did miss a message, or your functions didn't handle it well enough, you'll receive an alert to check & correct errors.

Comment: Interesting perspective. I have never thought of separating them into two separate processes/systems. Let me think abit more about this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally agree with @nineedm's and answer, but there are also other solutions.

If you introduce cache, you will always face cache revalidation problem - you have to mark cache as invalid when data were changed. Sometimes it is easy, depending on nature of cached data and how often data are changed.

If you have just single application, MemoryCache can be enough with proper specified expiration options.
If there is a cluster - you have to look at Distributed Cache solutions, for example Redis. There is MS article about that [Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1)